# Why are not my down votes counted?

Tags: support, down-votes

I'm trying to do down votes when I see that a post is not useful. The website tells me in a blue box that I could comment, what would I want to improve. Nevertheless, when I go to my profile and come back, my comment and down vote disappeared.

Why is this happening? I think it's somehow like a *lag*.

**Note: I do have enough reputation $\longrightarrow$ Reputation $\gt$ 125**

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page? And BTW how can you be sure that your downvote disappeared - privilege to see number of downvotes and upvotes separately [comes at 1k](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right: it's somehow like a lag. The technical term is [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache). The process goes like this:

1. You get a question page from the server
2. You vote or comment on the page. This has two effects:

   a) The information about your action is sent to the server

   b) Locally, your vote/comment are added to the page by JavaScript, so you can see what you did. Such local changes only affect the page as it's seen right now; they vanish on another pageload.
3. Now you navigate to another page and then come back. To save the networking and computational resources, you are not given an updated version of the page: it's considered that the page you looked at a few seconds ago is still good enough. In particular, this page does not reflect your vote or comment.
4. Solution: hit refresh (F5) to see the updated page, reflecting your actions.

Background reading: [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how)

Comment: Thanks. Another question: Why do I not get my badge of *critic*? Same reason? Takes time?

Comment: You'll get it soon. Badges are issued by a script that runs on a schedule, at some intervals.

Comment: Oh... okay. Thanks.